# iOS MagicalRecord Unable to Save To Persistent Store

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Right now I've created a separate child context called editContext, initialized like so:

```
self.editContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]];
```

I make some edits to an object in this context, namely changing one of the object's primitive values. However, when I run

```
[self.editContext MR_saveToPersistentStore];
```

I get the error logs:

```
Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x1781cb310): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
2014-09-03 08:32:46.629 Lockitron[1918:1e03] → Save Parents? 1
2014-09-03 08:32:46.630 Lockitron[1918:1e03] → Save Synchronously? 1
2014-09-03 08:32:46.641 Lockitron[1918:1e03] NO CHANGES IN ** DEFAULT ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
```

So it seems like editContext is saving properly, but its parent (defaultContext) is not because there are no changes. Why is this? I am definitely changing the primitive values as I check their values before the save.

Comment: Do not use contextForCurrentThread. You will get random crashes because of threading access. This method has been deprecated.